# Sentencia de actualizar

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Necesito ayuda para actualizar una sentencia estoy confundido si estoy concatenando correctamente,aqui esta mi setencia

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (id > 0)
        {
            //textBox1.Text = obs;
            DialogResult pregunta;
            pregunta = MessageBox.Show("Desea agregar una descripcion al articulo" + id + "?","", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (pregunta == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                 //Aqui es donde tengo la duda sobre la concatenacion
                con.ejecutar_sql("update tbl_Inventario set Detalles = " + textBox1.Text +
                    " where id_inventario =" + id);
                cargarTabla();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Lo que faltan son las comillas simple para el texto en Textbox1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (id > 0)
    {
        //textBox1.Text = obs;
        DialogResult pregunta;
        pregunta = MessageBox.Show("Desea agregar una descripcion al articulo" + 
                                   id + "?","", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        if (pregunta == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
             // Observa que hemos añadido una comilla simple después del signo igual
             // y tambien antes del where.
            con.ejecutar_sql("update tbl_Inventario set Detalles = '" + 
                              textBox1.Text +
                              "' where id_inventario =" + id);
            cargarTabla();
        }
    }
}
```

Habiendo añadido esas comillas tu sentencia quedaría así con valores inventados para el ejemplo:

**update tbl_Inventario set Detalles = 'abcd...' where id_inventario = 4**

Siempre que quieras construir una sentencia mediante concatenación recuerda que los textos han de ir entre comillas simples.